# I need to merge values of array based on properties of object, typescript

Tags: typescript

i have an array like:

```
example = [{
"prop": "test",
"propId": [1]
},
{
"prop": "test",
"propId": [2]
},
{
"prop": "test",
"propId": [3]
},
{
"prop": "test2",
"propId": [4]
},
{
"prop": "test2",
"propId": [5]
" 
]
```

i need to merge then and push the value of the propId based on that value, the output i expected looks like:

```
output = [
{
"prop": "test",
"propId": [1, 2 ,3]
},
{
"prop":"test2",
"propId": [4, 5]
}]
```

i can't hard code test or test2, these were dynamic values that comes from an api, the example is just a short version

Comment: Each property key (on the left from the “:”) can only appear once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple reducer function should do the trick

```js
const example = [
  {
    prop: "test",
    propId: [1]
  },
  {
    prop: "test",
    propId: [2]
  },
  {
    prop: "test",
    propId: [3]
  },
  {
    prop: "test2",
    propId: [4]
  },
  {
    prop: "test2",
    propId: [5]
  }
];

const groupProps = (propArr) =>
  propArr.reduce((result, el) => {
    const { prop, propId } = el;
    const found = result.find((el) => el.prop === prop);
    found ? found.propId.push(...propId) : result.push(el);
    return result;
  }, []);

console.log(groupProps(example));
```